# CMD - Replace everything BUT (string)

Tags: batch-file, replace, cmd

So I know there is a way to replace text in a variable using `%input:(string)=(newstring)%`.

This is my code:

```
@echo off
title Delete a File
color 02

:start
echo ---
echo Type "delete <file name>"
echo ---
set /p input="console> "
```

Now what I want to do is that if someone types `delete (filename)` I want to remove (filename) and only leave the word `delete`. What makes this very hard to is that (filename) could be anything.
Basically I want to do is remove everything from the variable but the word delete.. How do I do that ???

Comment: I think the easiest would be to break up  `delete (filename)` into two variables

Comment: So variable `input` should hold te word `delete` only finally? `"set input=delete"`?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something...but why capture "delete" at all? Why not just execute a branch of code if the line starts with the string "delete"?

Comment: RE: aschipfl - Yes but I need to set the (filename) to something.

Answer (score 0):

split your string:

```
set "input=delete filename"
echo %input%
for %%i in ("%input%") do set "input=%%i"
echo %input%
```